# X509Chain.Build() seems to ignore certificates in LocalComputer/My

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-6.0, x509certificate2

I need to rebuild a certificate chain based on the end certificate and then export all the certificates in the chain. For this I use the method `X509Chain.Build(endCertificate)`. My idea is that this way I can find all certificates as far as possible (from different sources, like folders (via `ChainPolicy.ExtraStore`) but also from all certificate stores of the system (like "My" or "Trusted Root Certification Authorities")).
If a certificate is missing, I ask the user to select it manually (and it will be copied to a folder which is an `ChainPolicy.ExtraStore` in the next run). This is repeated until all certificates are known and the chain can be built successfully.

However, I now have the problem that I noticed in my test that the chain cannot be built because an Intermediate CA certificate is supposedly missing. However, this certificate is located in "LocalComputer/My". It works if the certificate is in "LocalComputer/Intermediate Certification Authorities".

Therefore the question: How can I ensure that the entire certificate store (LocalUser and LocalComputer with all substores) is used to search for certificates?

*System: Windows 11 22H2; .NET-Version: net6.0-windows*

Comment: Are you making a connection with HTTPS (secure) which uses TLS for encryption and uses a certificate?  The TLs certificate need to be in both user and computer registry (stores).  TLS since Net 4.7.2 uses the OS for TLS.  Use to be done inside Net.  TLS the server sends a Certificate Block with names of certificate.  Then client machine looks up the names in the stores.  So the certificate has to be in a location that OS can locate the certificate.  Then for TLS to be secure you only want decrypted message to be read by the user.  So user needs the certificate as well.

Comment: I do not use the certificates directly. I'm just trying to put the chain together and then export the certs. I'll need the chain later on another system. There the user must put all the certificates in the chain in a folder (This is third party software, so that's the only way I can do it). The tool should therefore help to quickly find all the certificates that are required and then make them available for export.

Comment: If you have all the certificates in one location than any certificate can be used so it  may look like a certificate is used.  With TLS the server sends a certificate block with a list of certificate names.  Than client can choose any of the certificates.  The client code can specify a particular certificate by name so only one is chosen.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to examine the certificate block which is not encrypted.  All it contains is the names of possible certificates.  Uploading make a connection so at least one certificate is needed to do the upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default certificate verification will not look at certificate stores such as `My` for trusted roots. You can add other stores to the `ExtraStore` property if you want.

You also need to set `X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority` otherwise it will still be rejected. Note that **this could cause a major security issue**, depending on your use case, and you may want to do other manual checks on the trust chain.

```cs
using var store1 = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.AddRange(store1.Certificates);
chaim.VerificationFlags |= X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;
chain.Build(someCert);
```

`StoreName.Root` `CertificateAuthority` and `TrustedPeople` are used by default, and `AuthRoot` is a subset of `Root`. It makes no sense to use `Disallowed` so that leaves you with `My` `AddressBook` and `TrustedPublisher` to add. That is for both `StoreLocation.LocalMachine` and `CurrentUser`. Again `CurrentUser` is more of a security risk.

Put all stores in a `using` to dispose them when done.

---

Ideally you would store intermediate and root certificates in the correct place in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think it will be a security issue as I'm just tryinig to build the chain to export it later. I do not derive any trust from this. Trust is a separate topic in the legacy third party system. This system just needs all the certificates of the chain, to build the chain. Then it will check seperatly for trust. One last question: Which stores do I need to add (because they are not included by default) or can I simply add all substores from LocalComputer and LocalUser?

Comment: `StoreName.Root` `CertificateAuthority` and `TrustedPeople` are used by default, and `AuthRoot` is a subset of `Root`. It makes no sense to use `Disallowed` so that leaves you with `My` `AddressBook` and `TrustedPublisher`. That is for both `LocalMachine` and `CurrentUser`. Again `CurrentUser` is more of a security risk, but if you don't care then it doesn't matter. Put all stores in a `using` to dispose them when done.